# Eclipse Debugging: Disable Debug and browser output

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

I have an issue with eclipse when I want to debug my php application with PHP Debug.

I want to prevent eclipse to permanently open the debug console when I am starting debugging. <strike>(The actual problem is, that eclipse is crashing, if the (very usless) debug and browser output is shown.)</strike>

What I have to do?

---

Some hopefully relevant information:

- My eclipse system:

```
Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers

Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
```

- A screenshot showing the browser and debug output:

**screenshot eclipse browser output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:

Window > Preferences > PHP > Debug > Workbench Options > Open PHP Debug Views

Then disable (uncheck): Open PHP Debug Views (Debug output, Browser output)

That should help you, don't forget to close the tabs if they are already opened. After that, tabs should not open again.

[image]